# Migrating Hadoop Application From Development Environment To Production

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, oozie, hadoop2

We are working on a POC to build a data lake in Hadoop. In this regard we are evaluating ETL tools(Talend,Sqoop), Pig scripts,HIVE,Ooozie,Spark etc.. on top of Hadoop.

The clarity I am looking into is,

1. How to plan efforts/code release from development environment to       production?
2. How to plan release of hadoop based applications from  development environment to production environment?
3. When the release/migration happens between dev to production environments,    what all needs to be moved?any recommendations, do's    and dont's?
4. How to move pig scripts,HIVE (metastore/tables),Oozie configurations from development environment to production?

Also most important, are there any Java components required apart from HIVE/PIG/OOzie? If yes how to move these java components into hadoop?

Is there any possibility we can write some custom utilities in java and make them available in hadoop context? These java components will be used by Hive,Pig etc...

Any replies and guidance will be appreciated.

-Prakhyat M M

Comment: Hi Prakhyat,  were you able to find any best practices for production deployment.

Comment: Hi Prahalad, no articles on best practices as such, but I could experience each vendor like Hortonworks, Cloudera etc have there own way principles or process of handling all these cases.